# Run a macro on a workbook, and have it count all the rows in the work book, even if sheets are added later

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a Macro on a an excel file that is updated daily.

This file is currently set to X amount of pages, but always has the possibility of having 1 or 2 sheets added.

Is there a code that could count every row in the workbook, and will also  run a count  onthe rows in a workbook with sheets added later on?

So the macro will count all rows in workbook 1; with sheets 1,2,3,4

The same macro should be able to count all rows in workbook 1; with sheets 1,2,3,4 with a sheet 5 added later.

I currently only have the rows counted in each sheet on its on by pulling the sheet name. But I can not figure out how to have it count an additional sheet rows that would not be in the original excel file.

```
Dim sw As Worksheet
 Dim accum As Long
 Dim rowcounter As Long
 accum = 0
    For Each sw In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    rowcounter = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    accum = rowcounter + accum
    Next sw

Range("B35").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "= " & accum & ""
```

above is the current code I am running.

Comment: Show your code and what you have tried.  To answer the current question, "Yes, there is code that can do that," and for most questions, the answer is yes it is possible.  Please ensure that your post has an objective question, typically related to your code and specific issues/errors you are experiencing.

Comment: hi.for start u can use " For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets " to cycle all sheets in the book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used For each...Next to loop each worksheets, but you didn't put reference on the cells. You are basically repeat the counting on the active sheet.

```
Dim sw As Worksheet
Dim accum As Long
Dim rowcounter As Long
Dim strMsgbox  As String
accum = 0
For Each sw In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    rowcounter = sw.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    accum = rowcounter + accum
    strMsgbox = strMsgbox & vbNewLine & sw.Name & " rows: " & rowcounter
Next sw

'Range("B35").Value = accum
MsgBox strMsgbox & vbNewLine & "Total Rows: " & accum
```